# Student record for students that have continued and/or graduated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to find the complete student record for students that have continued and/or graduated covering a six year period. I did the following, but not sure if I am getting the right student record.

```
SELECT *
FROM FileYear2006
INNER JOIN GraduationFile1
ON FileYear2006.STUDENTID = GraduationFile1.STUDENTID
```

I believe the above query is giving me only the students that graduated, but I am not sure about the continued students.

I have FileYear2006-2012 and I have three GraduationFile1 for years 2009-2010, GraduationFile2 for years 2010-2011, and GraduationFile3 for years 2011-2012.

continued means that the student started for example in 2006, dropped out and came back in 2008.

Comment: Try with a left join and look for null columns.

Comment: Not clear on the criteria: did the actual graduation/continuation event need to take place during the six year period, or did they just have to be a student during this period, but they could have graduated at any time, including dates following the period in question?

Comment: Also, table and columns with year/month suffixes are almost always a horrible awful design choice. In this case, the year should be a column, and if you're worried about size/performance you make the year the first field in the clustered index on the table.

Comment: Also not clear on your table structure. What does a continued student mean in your system? Until you can answer that, you're jumping the gun even thinking about code.

Comment: I have FileYear2006-2012 and I have three GraduationFile1 for years 2009-2010, GraduationFile2 for years 2010-2011, and GraduationFile3 for years 2011-2012

Answer (score 0):

you may have some status column which keeps track of the students either passed/ dropped/ rejoined/ failed / continued etc you may set some codes for them like column name will be Student_Status and it may have values like below mapping

passed = 0, failed = 1, dropped = 2, rejoined = 3, continued = 4

then you can use your above Query with a check on Student_Status after your join in above query it will give you exact results for required students.

```
SELECT *
FROM FileYear2006
INNER JOIN GraduationFile1 ON FileYear2006.STUDENTID = GraduationFile1.STUDENTID
WHERE Student_Status = 4
```

Comment: yes as it will give you required results according to student_status value specified by you